# Mapping complex Observable json to class or interface

Tags: json, angular

I have an API I am consuming with a service in Angular 8.0.0. I cannot seem to understand how to map the json returned to an object.

All of the examples I have seen have been simple examples of an array of clearly defined and easily traversed json. The json set I am getting back is quite complex.

Ideally, since there is a lot of repeated patterns in there, I would make a class with other classes as members of the class.

1. Is there a way to just transform the returned observable json into the associated dictionary of dictionaries?
2. If I were to template this, I'm struggling with the fact that I get a dictionary back and not an array.

Here is the service design pattern that I am following. Since this design pattern transforms a simple json payload into a simple interface, it's not complex enough for me to try and transpose to my use-case. I have doubt on the ability to transform this complex dataset to an interface or class.

```
getTeams() {
    return this.http.get<ITeam[]>(this._url).pipe(
      retry(1), catchError(error => {
        return throwError(error.message || 'Undefined Server Error');
      }));
  }
```

Here is my sample dataset similar to what I am trying to consume in my angular component via my service:

```
{
    "stlouis_teams": {
        "blues": {
            "version": "12.0-57.24",
            "image": "stl_team_photo.jpg",
            "image_md5": "fffffc429735ffff4d6c716c113f3ffff",
            "stadium_phones": {
                "landlines": [
                    "210-555-1212",
                    "309-555-1212"
                ],
                "cells": [
                    "312-555-1212",
                    "502-555-1212"
                ]
            },
            "coaching_staff": {
                "coach": {
                    "image": "bill_brasky.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "4444444d0a2c1cad1437570f0e4444444"
                },
                "asst_coach": {
                    "image": "bill_billy.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "333333333d0a2c1cad1437570f0e33333333"
                }
            }
        },
        "jv_blues": {
            "version": "1.0-0.0",
            "image": "jv_stl_team_photo.jpg",
            "image_md5": "9999c42973599994d6c716c113f39999",
            "stadium_phones": {
                "landlines": [
                    "210-555-1111",
                    "309-555-1111"
                ],
                "cells": [
                    "312-555-1111",
                    "502-555-1111"
                ]
            },
            "coaching_staff": {
                "coach": {
                    "image": "bill_brasky.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "4444444d0a2c1cad1437570f0e4444444"
                },
                "asst_coach": {
                    "image": "bill_billy.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "333333333d0a2c1cad1437570f0e33333333"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "chicago_teams": {
        "blackhawks": {
            "version": "11.33",
            "image": "chi_team_photo.jpg",
            "image_md5": "00000c42973500004d6c716c113f30000",
            "stadium_phones": {
                "landlines": [
                    "702-555-1212",
                    "412-555-1212"
                ],
                "cells": [
                    "217-555-1212",
                    "904-555-1212"
                ]
            },
            "coaching_staff": {
                "coach": {
                    "image": "bill_brasky.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "4444444d0a2c1cad1437570f0e4444444"
                },
                "asst_coach": {
                    "image": "bill_billy.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "333333333d0a2c1cad1437570f0e33333333"
                }
            }
        },
        "minor_blackhawks": {
            "version": "1002.2",
            "image": "minor_chi_team_photo.jpg",
            "image_md5": "ccccccc42973500004d6c716c113fccccc",
            "stadium_phones": {
                "landlines": [
                    "702-555-2222",
                    "412-555-2222"
                ],
                "cells": [
                    "217-555-2222",
                    "904-555-2222"
                ]
            },
            "coaching_staff": {
                "coach": {
                    "image": "bill_brasky.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_brasky.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "4444444d0a2c1cad1437570f0e4444444"
                },
                "asst_coach": {
                    "image": "bill_billy.jpg",
                    "image_locations": {
                        "http": [
                            "http://example.com/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "http://example.com/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ],
                        "ftp": [
                            "ftp://example.com/public/images/bill_billy.jpg",
                            "ftps://example.com/secure/aoe124/public/images/bill_billy.jpg"
                        ]
                    },
                    "image_md5": "333333333d0a2c1cad1437570f0e33333333"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to map it? Can we see the interface, or the format you want it to be in?

Comment: I can see your problem, do you have access to api code, i.e., can you change the api code to return array of teams instead of dictionary of teams?

Comment: Could you use a json to interface tool like this https://transform.now.sh/json-to-ts-interface/ ?

Comment: @wentjun I'm just designing this and trying to not get off on the wring foot. At the end of the day, I would be ok with just taking the data as-is into an associative array.

Comment: @DipenduPaul Unfortunately, I believe I am forced to take the data as-is.

Comment: @Shannon Cool tool! So, I was sort of already headed down this path by hand. Where I am stuck is how to I map each object and attribute in the json to the interfaces? I have not found an example of this anywhere yet.

Comment: So, I just did an observable to <any> and got what I needed. Thanks all and sorry to bother.

Comment: ```  getAllTeams() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._url).pipe(
      retry(1), catchError(error => {
        return throwError(error.message || 'Undefined Server Error');
      }));
  }```